# Column defs for populating list of String in ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a grid getting populated from a list of String. This will be a single column table with each row containing one entry from the list.

```
data: ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
```

I can't figure out how to use columnDef in my situation. Tried below combinations:

1. without column defs -> failed, each character in string got separated into its own column
2. with one column def,

   `columnDefs: [{
            displayName: 'Path',
            width: '99%',
       }]`  <- failed, no value populated at all

I want the data to be populated in a single column with a displayName if possible.
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a columnDef for this simple grid.

```
$scope.myData = [{Path: 'test1'}, {Path: 'test2'}, {Path: 'test3'}]

$scope.gridOptions = {data: 'myData'}
```

Comment: umm, I can't have `{Path: 'test1'}`, the thing is this data comes from a Java object which is a list of Strings. The data at the js side is as an array ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

Comment: You will have to modify this data in the format `[{fieldName:data}]` even if you use a columnDef. You can write a single line of code to modify your java returned array in JS. The thing is that you need to comply by the format if you need to use this component. Please understand that you need to tell the grid what to display and where.

Comment: modifying the data to fit this format worked, I didn't want to do that initially, but looks like that is the easiest solution, thank you